# Implementing a tic tac toe board in python

Tags: python, game, numpy, tic-tac-toe

This is my attempt at making a class to represent a game board for tic tac toe. I normally hate `while` loops but I used one because I cant seem to make the `for` loop look nice for the display.

```
import numpy as np

class TicTacToeBoard():
    """Class to represent a board for a game of tic tac toe"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the board data"""
        self.dimension = 3,3
        self.board_data = np.array(range(1,10), dtype=object).reshape(self.dimension)
        self.space_to_coordinate = {}
        self.last_marked_coordinate = None

        for coord in np.ndindex(self.board_data.shape):
            space = self.board_data[coord]
            self.space_to_coordinate[space] = coord

    def display(self):
        """Displays the game board to console

        Example:
                1 | 2 | 3
                ----------
                4 | 5 | 6
                ----------
                7 | 8 | 9
        """
        count = 1
        while count < 10:
            coordinate = self.space_to_coordinate[count]
            space_data = self.board_data[coordinate]
            print(str(space_data)) if not count % 3 else print(str(space_data) + " |", end=' ')
            print('----------') if not count % 3 and count != 9 else None
            count += 1
        print()

    def is_marked(self, space):
        """Checks if space is marked returns false if not marked"""
        coordinate = self.space_to_coordinate[space]
        space_data = self.board_data[coordinate]
        if space_data == "X" or space_data == "O":
            return True
        return False

    def add_mark(self, space, mark):
        """If space is not marked, then add player mark and return true else return false"""
        if not self.is_marked(space):
            coordinate = self.space_to_coordinate[space]
            self.board_data[coordinate] = mark
            self.last_marked_coordinate = coordinate
            return True
        return False

    def is_winner(self, mark):
        """Checks to see if mark has won the board by getting '3 in a row' """
        if self.last_marked_coordinate == None:
            return False

        row_win, column_win, diag1_win, diag2_win = [True] * 4
        fixed_row, fixed_column = self.last_marked_coordinate
        for i in range(3):

            #check row
            if self.board_data[fixed_row, i] != mark:
                row_win = False

            #check column
            if self.board_data[i, fixed_column] != mark:
                column_win = False

            #check diagnol 1
            if self.board_data[i,i] != mark:
                diag1_win = False

            #check diagnol 2
            if self.board_data[i, 2-i] != mark:
                diag2_win = False

        return any([row_win, column_win, diag1_win, diag2_win])
```

NOTE: just realized I forgot to test for a cats game.